# CanLoad return true but do nothing

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a problem with canLoad that return true but do nothing .
My project is with angular v11.

My code :

```
canLoad(): Observable<boolean> {
    console.log('routing init login guard');
    return this.auth.isAuthenticated$.pipe(take(1),
      map((isAuth: boolean) => {
        if (isAuth) {
          console.log('*************GUARD: Authenticated !!!!!!******************');
          this.showLoadingIndictator().then(() => {
            this.auth.idTokenClaims$.subscribe((userInfos) => {
              this.shopperCrud.getShopperInfos(userInfos).subscribe({
                next: () => {
                  return true;
                },
                error: (error) => {
                  if (error.status === 404) {
                    this.router.navigate(['/account']).finally(() => this.loadingController.dismiss());
                    return false;
                  }
                }
              })
            })
          })
        } else {
          this.showLoadingIndictator().then(() => {
            this.auth
              .buildAuthorizeUrl()
              .pipe(mergeMap((url) => Browser.open({ url, windowName: '_self' })))
              .subscribe(() => {
                this.loadingController.dismiss();
              });
          });
          return isAuth;
        }
      })
    )
  }
```

with my routing:

```
  {
    path: 'main',
    loadChildren: () => import('./main/main.module').then(m => m.MainPageModule),
    canLoad: [LoginGuard],
  },
```

This works when I get an error, so I'm redirected to /account.
But when it's true, I have to go to /main but the spinner becomes invisible and the screen is white.

Thank you,
tell me if you need some informations

Comment: The subscribe in there is a red flag.

Comment: Okay. Everything in your subscribe inside your then runs async. The code will just continue past that and any returns in there will not return to anything. You need to combine that inner observable with your outer observable using something like a swtichMap.. does that help a bit more?